# Error saving data in Core Data (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

My program receives the JSON data from the Web service. Next, the program stores the data in the database using Core Data. If I call the save data after adding each entry, everything works, but very slowly. Keeping 200 entries takes more than one minute.

If I execute saving only once at the end – the program throw exception.

```
- (void) onLoadMessages:(NSObject*)object {  
    NSArray *messages = (NSArray*)object;  
    if (messages==nil) {  
        [self onError:@"Message array is null"];  
        return;  
    }  

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];  
    long now = [date timeIntervalSince1970];  
    Boolean update = false;  
    for(int i=0; i<messages.count; i++) {  
        NSDictionary *m = messages[i];  
        Message *msg = [[Message alloc]initWithDictionary:m];  
        if ([self UpdateMessage:msg UpdateTime:now])  
            update = true;  
    }  
    if (update) {  
        NSError *error = nil;  
        // Error throw here  
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])  
            [self onError2:error];  
    }  
}  

- (Boolean) UpdateMessage:(Message*) msg UpdateTime:(long)now {  
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.  
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];  
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];  

    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", msg.id];  
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id=%@)", s];  
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];  

    NSError *error;  
    NSArray *object = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];  

    Boolean result = false;  
    if (object==nil)  
        [self onError2:error];  
    else {  
        NSManagedObject *m;  
        if ([object count]==0) {  
            // Insert new message  
            m = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Messages"  
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];  
            [m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:msg.id] forKey:@"id"];  
            [m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:msg.agancy.id] forKey:@"agancy"];  
            [m setValue:msg.header forKey:@"header"];  
            [m setValue:msg.keywords forKey:@"keywords"];  
            [m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:msg.indate] forKey:@"indate"];  
            [m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:now] forKey:@"updated"];  
            result = true;  
      } else {  
            // Update message  
            m = [object objectAtIndex:0];  
            [m setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:now] forKey:@"updated"];  
        }  

        // Save the context.  
        // Too long execution  
        /*NSError *error = nil; 
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
            [self onError2:error];*/  

    }  
    return result;  
}
```

Help correct the behavior of the program.

With respect,
Alexander.

P.S.
Execution takes place in the main thread.

Field "Id" for table "Messages" indexed.

Comment: Which exception you have exactly?

Comment: Thread 1:signal SIGABRT
And crush application :(

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding privateObjectContext!

_privateObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

And replace managedObjectContext on privateObjectContext when updating/inserting data/